# Geometry of Vectors

Tags: vector-analysis

I know the definition of collinear vectors and the condition for collinearity says "Two vectors $a$ and $b$ are collinear if $a=kb$, $k$ being non-zero scalar" but I am confused if $k=0$ then will not they be collinear? If $k=0$, then $a=0$ but $b$ is any vector, since zero vector has arbitrary direction then any vector $b$ and zero vector can be thought of as lying on parallel lines which implies that $b$ and zero vector are collinear i.e $k=0$ is valid for collinearity. Please help me.

Comment: The definition as written is a bad one as it's not even symmetric in $\bf a$ and $\bf b$. Probably it's better to say that two vectors are collinear if one is contained in the span of the other, or equivalently, that they're contained in the same $1$-dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 1):

We ask that $k \neq 0$ because we want to avoid trivial, useless solutions.

It's analogous to insisting that 1 is not a prime number.

If we allowed $k=0$ then any two vectors would be [linearly dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence).

If any two vectors are linearly dependent, then all vectors would be linearly dependent. (Linear dependency is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).)

The only vector space would be the trivial vector space $\{{\bf 0}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, nul-vector is collinear to all other vectors.
So, yes, you could say that $k\ge0$, but i guess there are other reasons behind why we don't do so.